# Reload a View after Closing its subView

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, swift5, viewwillappear

I have a UIViewController named A, Im adding a another controller to the A controller like this

```
  self.AView = (self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BView") as? BViewController)!

  self.addChild(self.BView)

  self.BView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height - 450, width: self.view.frame.width , height: 450)
  self.view.addSubview((self.BView.view)!)
  self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.BView.view)
```

And I am closing this by using the function below

```
func closeCurrentView(){

   self.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

After closing this I need to reload My Aview

I have added this in My Aview but not getting called after Closing the BView

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(true)
}
```

Comment: Irrelevant to the issue, you should't hardcode parameters that you send to any super call. Instead call it like this `super.viewWillAppear(animated)`

Comment: yeah okay! but still my issue not yet resolved

Comment: Yes. That's what `irrelevant to the issue` means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

viewWillAppear method is called only when the view will enter in the view hierarchy, in this case before BView is removed AView is already in the view hierarchy even if not visible (so AViewController.viewWillAppear is not called when BView is removed). You have two options:

1. Pass a reference of AViewController to BViewController (during initialization or later) so you can do this in BViewController class:

```
func closeView(){
   self.view.removeFromSuperview()
   self.AViewController.view.layoutIfNeeded() // or do something else to update AView
}
```

2. Remove BView in AViewController class:

```
func closeBView(){
   self.BViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
   self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // or do something else to update AView
}
```